# former student ID vs old student ID

Tags: adjectives, attributives

Happy New Year!

Given that a student has graduated from ABC School.
When she wants to remind her teacher of her with her student ID.

(1): My former student ID was 12345678
(2): My old student ID was 12345678
(3): My student ID was 12345678
(4): your suggeston

I am so confused of the first two sentences because they sound like that I ever had a student of my own whose student ID was 12345678.

Comment: all are fine, don't overthink it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were talking about a former student of **yours**, *student* would be in the genitive case:

> My former student's ID was 12345678.

So all of your suggestions are acceptable. The first two imply you have a new student ID number, though, but the third would work whether you have a new student ID or not.

Comment: Don't know why I got a downvote here. My answer is the only one that explains why the first two options aren't wrong, which was part of the question. Is it 'genitive case'? Do we not use that in English?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt (1) or (2) would be misunderstood. But one might wonder if you now have a *new* student ID.

But

> (3): My student ID was 12345678.

is fine. Using past tense is enough to understand when it was.

Comment: I agree. If you needed to be specific, you would add the name of the school: My ABC student ID was 12345678.

Answer (score 0):

You asked that she wants to *remind* her teacher with an ID she **had** when she was in the school. And your perplexity is you don't want to use something that also means that the student has some student whose ID was '1...8'

Out of some, one such way is...

> ***Your*** former student with an ID 'X'

Trust me, I did this recently (However, I included the batch year as well!), and my teacher just got it!